# How to conditionally render a screen in React native but place it on to stack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have this:

```
  const initialRouteName = leagueId ? 'League' : 'Leagues'
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={initialRouteName}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Leagues"
      >
        {(props: any) => <MyLeagues navigation={props.navigation} theme={theme} />}
      </Stack.Screen>

      <Stack.Screen
        name="League"
      >
        {(props: any) => {
          return <League leagueId={leagueId} theme={theme} />
        }}
      </Stack.Screen>
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

now this works (sort of). I've changed this behaviour that when I use PNs if the `leagueId` exists, then it will "navigate" the user to the correct screen.

however, the behaviour use to be if you clicked on the tab where this stack is initiated it would go back to the `Leagues` screen. it doesn't do that now as I've set the `initialRouteName` to be `League`, so I guess `Leagues` isn't on the stack. is there a way to make sure I render `League` screen initially if `leagueId` exists but also allow it to go back? if that makes sense

Comment: is it possible to `navigate` to the `League` from `Leagues` and pass the `leagueId` as a param like that instead? I feel like this issue is due to trying to handle the navigation flow in the stack.

Comment: Hi, I've encountered this too, have you solved this?